# Using Photo points to "geotag" old images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotag

I have a bunch of old aerial images(in jpg format), however they do not contain any coordinates.
I have a shape file which has the coordinates of the images and one of the attributes is the image file name. ( i assume that it will be the center point of these images)

Is there a way to "geotag" or to pin the photos to these points using QGIS?

There are about 6000 aerial photos.

Comment: Have you tested your hypothesis that the shapefile point is the centre? It should be easy enough to look at a point on Google Maps and as long as at least some shadow of your old image exists in today's ground truth you should be able to confirm this. Are the images taken looking straight down or at an angle? Do they all cover the same area on the ground? Are they all aligned N-S? I'm not sure doing 6000 manually with the QGIS Georeferencer is a good idea, and we need to know more before we can propose something automatic.

Answer (score 1):

For a QGIS solution, if you know the size of the image in pixels and also what size each pixel is you should be able to georeference the images by calculating the corner locations as per this question: [Georeference image using center point and size?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340981/georeference-image-using-center-point-and-size)

The documentation for gdal-translate is here: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html

This can relatively easily be integrated into a geoprocessing script to process all of your data.